# How much import tax on electronics is being enforced on personal laptops, smartphones and IPads in Thailand?

Tags: thailand, electronic-items, import-taxes

We are family of 4 (2 kids (5 and 7) + 2 adults) coming from UK to Bangkok this January, each will be bringing their laptop (4 total), smartphone (3 total) and kids will also have their Ipads (2), and also other gadgets... after [doing some research](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52859/bringing-brand-new-ipad-and-tablet) it would appear [there is import tax in Thailand for electronics](http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-Thailand/). So in theory every tourist should be charged on their electronics (which I highly doubt they do). However I think we are bringing in more electronics that 'average' family would, so this gives me a bit of worry... Has anyone been charged tax on their electronics?

**How much import tax on electronics is being enforced on personal laptops, smartphones and IPads in Thailand?**

Comment: Your kids are 5 & 7, and they each are bringing a laptop and a tablet?  Isn't travel a good time for kids to be unplugged and discover the world?

Comment: Hi Tom, heh try telling them that,.... it is incredibly effective tool to control them,... threats of computers taken away are not taken lightly in our family,... ;)

Comment: Taught my daughter early on, when we go somewhere we go to see new things.  She gets her tablet on the plane and once in a while in the hotel room if there is absolutely nothing else to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**It's not enforced at all**, and more importantly, it's not even applicable: as a tourist it's clear that you'll be exporting whatever you bring in, particularly if it's used.

The regulations are there for professional importers, including people with undeclared suitcases full of identical, shrink-wrapped products.

For what it's worth, I've traveled extensively to Thailand for work and pleasure and have gone through customs 30+ times, nearly always carrying one or two laptops, multiple mobiles, etc.  I've never been asked a single question about electronics.

Comment: But, as for all these goods that you 'own' and take across borders: it is wise to have a copy of the purchase receipt with you if they look brand new, you may get asked where you bought it. And in countries with a lot of corruption, you should do that anyway. I have heard stories of people leaving a country they visited being accused of buying and *exporting* devices. That was years ago though, I don't know if that still applies.

Answer (score 7):

Thailand does not tax temporary imports, such as tourist's personal electronics.

It does tax items that are brought as gifts for a Thai resident, items for resale or items that will be left in the country for other reasons.

Thailand does not require you to declare personal items such as this, and as such won't even know (or care) what you have.

As jpatokal alluded to Thai Customs are fairly lax (I walked through with four higher end bicycles and they asked why, I said for my friends to ride and they waved me through).  But that said, they are getting much stricter on limits on alcohol and tobacco products, when they say you are allowed 1 liter duty free, they mean you are allowed 1 liter period.